# How do I print args when defined as a String Array in Scala?

Tags: scala, printing, read-eval-print-loop, args

This may just be me not understanding how to use REPL but I would like to be able to call
MyObject.myMethod("Hi") and print Hi or This is my message Hi

Here are some failed attempts:

```
object MyObject {
    def myMethod(args: Array[String]) {
      println("This is my message "+args)
    }
  }

object MyObject {
    def myMethod(args: Array[String]) {
      println(args.map(_.mkString(" "))
    }
  }
```

error: Server Timeout - possibly an infinite loop in your program.
Please be patient.
New interpreter instance being created for you, this may take a few seconds.

```
object MyObject {
    def myMethod(args: Array[String]) {
      println("Hello, " + args(0) + "!")
    }
  }
```

### error: Server Timeout - possibly an infinite loop in your program.

I am not sure if this is just a poor example to be using with the interpreter or if I am misunderstanding Array Strings in Scala or perhaps a bit of both.

Comment: To print the contents of an `Array` you need to use `array.deep` or `array.mkString(" ")`. Not sure what causes the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is missing a closing parenthesis in

```
println(args.map(_.mkString(" "))
```

and I think that's causing a huge amount of confusion (perhaps you're defining a recursive call since you're not realising that you're still defining the method and object.

Make sure you're at the REPL prompt

```
scala>
```

before defining the object and make sure that definition is complete before invoking it. I don't think your actual `println()` above is correct either, but correcting the parentheses will get you on the road.

Comment: I'm not sure what calling `mkString(" ")` does on a `String` but probably nothing useful...

Comment: `"hello".mkString(" ")` results in `h e l l o`

Answer (score 0):

Your calling the method wrongly at first. Try calling the method as

```
MyObject.myMethod(Array("Hello"))
```

Note the difference with

```
MyObject.myMethod("Hello")
```

Second use `arg.deep` or `mkString(" ")` in the method to display the string.

**EDIT**

Scala `Array`'s differs from java `Array` by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent reply korefn. It appears that my challenge lies in how to call the methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are spot on Korefn. It seems that knowing how to call the method is tripping me.

```
  object ScalaMain {
  case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

  val persons = List(
    Person("Boris", 40),
    Person("Betty", 32),
    Person("Bambi", 17))

  val (minors, majors) = persons.partition(_.age <= 18) 

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println (minors.mkString(", "))
    println (majors.mkString(", "))
  }
}
```

Is invoked by using

```
ScalaMain.main(null)
```

This results in:

```
Person(Bambi,17)
Person(Boris,40), Person(Betty,32)
```

Ref:
 http://michid.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/so-scala-is-too-complex/